# Splitting a string in bash on something specific

Tags: bash

I had a string I cut based on a colon. I now have a string in the format of:
`mon date, year Birthday` (input)

What can I do so I can just have:
mon date, year WITHOUT Birthday?
(or in other words a desired output of:)

```
Mon date, year
```

Clarification: Birthday in this case is literally the string "Birthday"

I know various posts on this website tell you how to split strings based on delimiters, but I have no idea how to split a string based on a specific word/string and couldn't find it on here

Comment: add input and desired output.

Comment: So you just want to remove `Birthday`? What does that have to do with splitting?

Comment: @melpomene yeah, didn't know how I would go about it so I just said splitting

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion `var="${var% Birthday}"`

Comment: @tso I've added it

Comment: i have seen. do like @melpomene said or do it with `sed`.

Answer (score 1):

with bash

```
orig="mon date, year Birthday"
val="${orig%% Birthday}"

echo $val
mon date, year
```

It's not exactly splitting that we do here, it's rather "stripping" off a fix suffix. bash has that built-in.

Answer (score 0):

with sed:

```
var=$(sed 's/ Birthday//'<<<'mon date, year Birthday')
echo $var
```

will print:

```
mon date, year
```

Comment: how would I store that into a variable?

Answer (score 0):

So I am using cut here. Let me know if this helps you.

```
val=$(echo "mon date, year Birthday" | cut -d" " -f1,2,3)
```

Comment: `cut` is not built into the shell.

Comment: @melpomene, thanks I have updated my answer by removing that statement. Request you to remove -ve if that was because of that statement, will be grateful to you.